# When do we need to specify and declare the storyboard variable when we add several storyboards to the project

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, segue

I'm working on a swift app and have a question about using several storyboards in the project.

I have two storyboards in my project, and I added the segue from the first View Controller in the storyboard to another storyboard. Since I wanted to pass the data in the segue, at first I wrote the following code in the first storyboard's prepare(for segue...) function,

```
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "secondStoryboard", bundle: nil)
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController()!
```

There were other issues and after I've done some refactoring, my prepare function becomes like,

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "toSecondVC") {
        // there is a table view and get the cell's title when move to another viewcontroller
        let row = (sender as! NSIndexPath).row
        let secondVC = segue.destination as! SecondViewController
        secondVC.cellTitle = cells[row].title   
    }
}
```

I deleted the storyboard variable and it works fine (I can see the cell's title in the print statement when I move to the second view controller.

I read some articles and I saw people declare storyboard variable when they have more than 2 of them. Since my app (which doesn't declare storyboard variable in prepare function) works fine, I was wondering if it's necessary to add this code, `let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "secondStoryboard", bundle: nil)`, when I add segue to different storyboard. Or do I just need to specify the view controller which I want to present next as I wrote like `let secondVC = segue.destination as! SecondViewController`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only time you need to instantiate the storyboard in code is when you’re not using a segue to move to it.

If you have two storyboards A and B and inside of A you create a segue arrow and point it to storyboard B (like you have done in your project), then that segue will instantiate the storyboard for you.

Just like how when you create a segue from one view controller to the next. You don’t have to then also instantiate the view controller in code. The segue that you create does that for you.

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick response! I just figured I do not need to instantiate the storyboard in code when I use the storyboard. Still, I'm confused about writing only code or using a storyboard, but this answer was really helpful. Thank you again!

Comment: @Yuuu you're welcome. The difference between using storyboards or writing only code is one of personal preference. Neither is objectively better than the other. If one way works for you, use it. If not, don't use it.   They are all tools in your toolbox that are there for you to choose from. There is no right or wrong tool to use. (Unless you pick up the wrench and use it like a hammer ).